# Не работает .focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не работает `.focus()`
В консоли `console.log` отрабатывает, а в `input` курсор не появляется, пока сам туда не кликнешь. Проверял в: `Chrome, Yandex, Mozilla, IE11 на Windows 10`

```js
$('.fa-search').click(function() {
  $('#searchField').focus();
  console.log('Focus Pocus');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
  <input id="searchField" type="search" class="search-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" name="s">
</form>
<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">Search</i>
```

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить установка фокуса через `setTimeout`

Comment: напишите плиз пример в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает нормально ваш пример кода.

```js
$('.fa-search').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#searchField').focus();
    console.log('Focus Pocus');
  }, 0);
});

$('.fa-search-2').click(function() {
  $('#searchField').focus();
  console.log('Focus Pocus');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
  <input id="searchField" type="search" class="search-field" value="лагутенко" name="s">
</form>
<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">icon</i>
<i class="fa fa-search-2" aria-hidden="true">icon 2</i>
```

Comment: поправил ваш код, вот так работает, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: у вас тут работает, а у меня не работает и после того как я написал setTimeout все стало нормально

Comment: вы предложили добавить setTimeout, но в вашем коде его не было, а по сути был скопирован мой исходный код, как же оно могло у меня заработать, если до этого не работало?

Comment: ни в одном из перечисленных не работало, а теперь работает

Comment: Зачем дважды одно и тоже писать в комментах? Я с первого раза понял и обновил вопрос.

Comment: Возможно оно работает при условии, что поиск всегда открыт, но если он скрыт, как у меня, то нужен setTimeout...

Comment: @eugene_v не было указана ОС, а это очень важно. Вообще странно, потому как у меня тоже вин 10 и хром, и в нем прекрасно работает. А у вас именно сниппет не работает? Или код на вашем сайет?